# Rails Simple Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a basic search that is not working and I dont understand why.

In my model I have this

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
    find(:all, :conditions => ['jobTitle LIKE ? OR jobDescription LIKE ?', search_condition, search_condition])
  end
end
```

A parameter does get passed to it then an error comes up:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "all" LINE 1: ...ngs".* FROM "postings" WHERE "postings"."id" IN ('all', '--... ^ : SELECT "postings".* FROM "postings" WHERE "postings"."id" IN ('all', '--- :conditions: - jobTitle LIKE ? OR jobDescription LIKE ? - "%drew%" - "%drew%" ')
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using outdated syntax for `find`.  Use `where` instead:

```
 def self.search(search)
   if search
     search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
     where(['jobTitle LIKE ? OR jobDescription LIKE ?', search_condition, search_condition])
   end
 end
```